# Simple Dockerfile no work

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stable
MAINTAINER xxxx <xxxx@xxxx.com>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Then, I run in the directory of Dockerfile:

```
docker build -t testimage .
```

Finally:

```
docker run -d testimage
```

The container no start:

```
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
c4fe93e2e225        test                "/bin/bash"         17 minutes ago      Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                       gloomy_ritchie
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run a detached container (`-d`), but you are also attempting to launch an interactive shell (`/bin/bash`).  Because `bash` requires an interactive terminal, it exits immediately, hence your container exits.

If you just want to run an interactive shell in your container, get rid of the `-d`:

```
docker run -it testimage
```

The `-it` flags set up the container for interactive use; see the man page for `docker-run` for more information.

A detached container is most often used to run a persistent service (like a database, or a web server), although you can run anything as long as it doesn't expect to be attached to an active terminal.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being so newbie.